# Log4j configured but no sql got printed out

Tags: spring, log4j, mybatis

I have latest spring+mybatis

```
Spring 4.2.3 + MyBatis 3.4+ MyBatis-Spring 1.3
```

I want to sql got printed out,so configured log4j like this:

```
# Console output...
log4j.appender.stdout                            = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target                     = System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold                  = ALL
log4j.appender.stdout.layout                     = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern   = %5p [%t] - %m%n
#log4j.logger.com.idpweb                      = TRACE
log4j.rootLogger                                 = ERROR,stdout
log4j.logger.org.springframework                 = DEBUG, stdout
# SqlMap logging configuration...
log4j.logger.com.company.dept.mapper.map.SeniorMapper= TRACE
log4j.logger.com.mybatis                             = TRACE
log4j.logger.java.sql                                = TRACE
log4j.logger.java.sql.Connection                     = TRACE
log4j.logger.java.sql.PreparedStatement              = TRACE
log4j.logger.java.sql.Statement                      = TRACE
log4j.logger.java.sql.ResultSet                      = TRACE
```

and project struct like this

```
Project
   src
   war
       WEB-INF
           applicationContext.xml
           logj.properties
```

But nothing got printed out when app running,so what is the problem?

Another problem is that after appending "fgsdfgsd" to the end of log4j.properties,then restart web app,no exception got thrown out,so I doubt that spring doesn't take

```
project/war/WEB-INF/log4j.properties
```

as it's logging configuration.So I moved log4j.properties to

```
project/log4j.properties,

nothing changed.
```

Comment: What application server are you using?

Comment: jetty is used for a  gwt app

Comment: just an advice: I would not spend time for fixing Log4J 1.x problems. Consider switching to Log4J 2.x. It has better architecture, webapp support and performance. And possibly your error will disappear during migration...

Comment: you show us your log4j configuration, but had you configured mybatis itself for use log4j? if not, take a look at http://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/logging.html

Comment: I have checked that,but don't know how to add it to spring config file:applicationContext.xml

Answer (score -1):

1、if you use maven project,then put the log4j.properties in the resources folder like this:
project/src/main/resources/log4j.properties
this is the default location where log4j try to locate its property file.

2、you can also specify you log4j config file in web.xml like this:

(1)add Log4jConfigListener

```
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

(2)add context param name 'log4jConfigLocation' to tell Log4jConfigListener where to locate the log4j.proterties

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/conf/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: I followed your suggestion,nothing got printed out in console.

Comment: you should config your mybatis mapper log level like this:log4j.logger.yourmapperpkg=debug

Comment: I think I should tell mybatis to use log4j explicity,otherwise it will use commons-loing by default,and the problem is that how I can add: <setting name="logImpl" value="LOG4J"/> to applicationContext.xml without add extra mybatis_config.xml

Comment: you can extend org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListene and add org.apache.ibatis.logging.LogFactory.useLog4JLogging();  in its constructor.

Comment: I have removed commons-logging.jar,and this should lead spring and mybatis to use log4j...jar,but still nothing got printed out

Comment: do you add <setting name="logImpl" value="LOG4J"/>  in mybatis_config.xml?